# Enable "Insert Virtual Indent on Enter" without Enabling "Allow Caret Placement After the End of Line"

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm attempting to replicate how new lines work in Visual Studio. Specifically, when pressing enter from the EOL, a new line is create with virtual indentation (i.e., the caret is placed at the correct indention without the tab and/or space characters being inserted). The tabs and/or spaces only get inserted when you start to type on the new line.

I may be mistaken (so, please correct me if I'm wrong), but this isn't a preference in Visual Studio and is just how it works.

In Rider, the closest I've gotten is enabling
`Settings > Editor > General > Typing Assistance > Insert Virtual Indent on Enter`
However, this automatically enables and requires
`Settings > Editor > General > Allow Caret Placement After the End of Line`

I dislike that I'm now unable to
(a) click anywhere beyond the EOL and have the caret be placed at the EOL.
(b) press the right arrow key to move the caret to the beginning of the following line from the EOL or Virtual Space.
(c) do similar arrow key text navigation to (b).

Obviously this isn't a big deal, it would just be nice to know whether it's possible. Likely due being unfamiliar with a Virtual Space feature such as this one, I'm not sure what benefit(s) it provides. So, I'm also open to reasons why it's beneficial to keep Virtual Space (after EOL) enabled.

Known Workarounds/Alternatives:
(1) I could disable the Virtual Space settings and enable the automatic removal of all trailing whitespace on save, which would net the same result at the end of the day.

(2) I know CTRL + Right Arrow Key would move the caret to the beginning of the following line (from the EOL or Virtual Space that follows).

(3) I also know END will move the caret to the true EOL (regardless of whether the caret is preceding the EOL or following it in the Virtual Space).

(4) I could create macros for specific/finer text navigation and apply them to my programmable keys or Stream Deck.